# Calculating Appliance Power Usage from Deep Cycle Battery

Tags: voltage, batteries, inverter, amperage, watts

I want to figure out a formula for calculating appliance usage from a deep cycle battery and 120v power inverter.  I own and operate a hot dog cart. I wish to add an electric grill/griddle to the cart in order to toast buns and open-face grill hot dogs.

The question is: what size and how many batteries do I need to run a grill spec'ed at 120v/14.6 amps/1750 watts for four or five hours? Of course, this assumes the worst case of running it at maximum power and constantly. I guess that would actually be best case scenario, since it would mean I was selling a lot of hot dogs.

So there you have it. I am sorry this question is so specific to myself.  But a formula would be applicable to all persons trying to calculate appliance power usage.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Additional info: most likely I will be using an AGM deep cycle battery.

Answer (score 1):

You can assume that the power inverter is about 85% efficient (more or less).  So you need 1750 Watts for 5 Hours = 8.75 KWH.  Multiply that by your efficiency (1 / .85) = ~ 10.3 KWH.

Assume that your battery is 12V under load towards the end of discharge.  10.3 KWH / 12V =~ 857 Amp Hours of capacity.

Another method: 120V = 12V * 10  .  So the current has to increase by the same ratio.
14.6 Amps * 10 * 5 hours * (1 / 0.85) =~ 859 Amp Hours.

That's an awful lot of batteries.  This is probably the reason that people use quiet generators that run from fuel of some sort.  The Honda Inverter generators are darned quiet and work *really* well.

Comment: Thanks Dwayne Reid. This is disappointing news on one hand making it about a $2000 investment (4 batteries, inverter, and appliance). On the other hand, propane is cheap and my cart already uses it.  That is the route I will investigate next.